# "object mycorpus could not found"

Tags: r, text-mining, word-cloud

I'm trying to make wordcloud. But I'm getting error as

> "Error in tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(tolower)) :    object
>   'myCorpus' not found"

I'm very new to R. Please suggest

---

```
library(tm)
library(tmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(wordcloud)
library(corpora)
library(RWeka)

setwd("C:/Users/deb/Desktop/R")

mydata <- read.csv("C:/Users/deb/Desktop/R/comm.csv",header = TRUE)

#myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource("C:/Users/deb/Desktop/R/comm.csv$comments))

myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus,content_transformer(tolower))
mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus, removeNumbers)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, make your question reproducible, adding an example of your data.

Comment: You are not defining myCorpus anywhere in your code. Look at your code and the commented line. I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: Consider defining the object `myCorpus` somewhere. I see you have a commented out line that does that?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to define "corpus" before using tm_map function

In your code, you have not specified any Corpus that you can define as below:

> mydata$text = text variable in mydata dataframe

```
library(tm)
library(lsa)
library(tmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(wordcloud)
library(corpora)
library(RWeka)
setwd("C:/Users/deb/Desktop/R")
mydata <- read.csv("comm.csv",header = TRUE)

corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(mydata$text))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
```

For more Support, you need to provide more details so we can deep drive on that.